# Unterschied zwischen „ausreichend” und „hinreichend”

Tags: meaning, difference

Welchen Unterschied gibt es zwischen *ausreichend* und *hinreichend?* Ich möchte gerne wissen, ob ich diese zwei Worte synonym benutzen kann.

Comment: Eigentlich (fast) dasselbe meinend habe ich „ausreichend” öfter in der Schule und „hinreichend” öfter im Studium gehört, aber das hilft natürlich nicht wirklich beim *Unterschied*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beide meinen (gerade) genug. Sie können in fast allen Fällen synonym gebraucht werden.

Es besteht ein winziger Unterschied in der Perspektive, der aus der eigentlichen Wortbedeutung resultiert. Wenn man *genug* als Hindernis sieht, ist **hinreichend** aus der Perpektive vor dem Hindernis (bis da *hin*), wohingegen **ausreichend** eher das Überschreiten des Hindernisses im Blick hat.

Beispiele

> Ich habe mich *hinreichend* auf die Prüfung vorbereitet.
>   Ich habe *ausreichend* gelernt um die Prüfung zu bestehen.

Answer (score 5):

Die Begriffe sind sehr ähnlich, sehe ich auch so.

Hier ist allerdings ein Fall, bei dem *hinreichend* deplatziert wäre, wahrscheinlich sogar falsch:

> »Für meine dreiwöchige Reise brauche ich ausreichend Unterhosen.«
>
> »Und das heißt?«
>
> »Dieser Haufen genügt.«

Und hier einer, bei dem *ausreichend*, jedenfalls für mein Empfinden, die schlechtere Lösung wäre:

> Das Urteil geht in Ordnung, der Mord an Dieter K. wurde hinreichend
> bewiesen.

Das zielende *hinreichend* verbindet i. A. Voraussetzung und Folge (hier: Beweis und Verurteilung), wogegen *ausreichend* gewöhnlich für eine Zustandsbeschreibung verwendet wird.

Comment: Ich kann nicht nachvollziehen, was an »ausreichend bewiesen« unüblich wäre. https://www.google.at/search?tbm=bks&hl=de&q=%22ausreichend+bewiesen%22 liefert über 4.000 Fundstellen.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Habe umformuliert, 4000 Österreicher sind ein Wort.

Comment: In mathematischen Texten hat _hinreichend_ eine formale Bedeutung die der umgangssprachlichen nahekommt. Dennoch würde kein Mathematiker ein _hinreichend_ durch ein _ausreichend_ ersetzen. (Siehe Seite 39 in Albrecht Beutelspacher „Das ist o.B.d.A. trivial!“, Vieweg, 1995.) Ob das allerdings auch in Österreich gilt weiß ich nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Ein Bedeutungsunterschied besteht so gut wie nicht. Der Unterschied liegt im Verwendungszusammenhang.

In der ganz normalen, unverkrampften Alltagssprache wird man gut und gerne etwas  ***genug***, ***genügend*** oder ***ausreichend*** finden. ***Hinreichend*** findet man Dinge in Kontexten von Bürokratie, Hierarchie, Technik und vielleicht in einigen Fachjargons.